# Render show view from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed

I have previewed all questions with similar topics and none of those solutions help me. I am attempting to create a twitter like feed that will display posts of a certain category in rails. 
This is my industries controller:

```
class IndustriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @wads = Wad.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def music
    @music_wads = Wad.where(category: "Music").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    @wad = @music_wads.pluck(:id)
  end
end
```

This is part of my posts controller:

```
class WadsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_wad, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @wads = Wad.all
    end

    def show
        @wad = Wad.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @wad = Wad.new
    end


    def create
        @wad = current_user.wads.build(wad_params)
        if @wad.save    
          redirect_to @wad
        else
          flash[:error] = 'Error try again'
          render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

And this is my show view for my industries controller:

```
<h1>Music Wads</h1>

<%= will_paginate @music_wads %>

<% @music_wads.each do |music_wad| %>
    <%= link_to 'wads/:id' do %>
    <div class="flex-rectangle">
        <%= music_wad.user.name  %>
        <%= music_wad.short_form %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
<%= will_paginate @music_wads %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get    '/industries', to: 'industries#index'
  get    '/music',    to:  'industries#music'
  get    '/tech',     to:  'industries#tech'


  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :wads 
end
```

I am attempting to make it so that clicking on a post among the lists of post carries you to page of that post (/wads/id). I've been baffled all day and am now at my wits end. I am aware I am a noob and this is a nooby question but any help would gladly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try with something like `<%= link_to wads_path(music_wad) do %>`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks a lot for the response! I just tried that and it seems we're getting close, however that redirects to '/wads.id' as opposed to 'wads/id'

Comment: you can type `rails routes` in the console and find the route you need (if you use rails 4 or lower type: `rake routes`)

Comment: @ZivGalili, I know that the route I need is 'wads/:id' but I don't know how to generate ':id' dynamically for each individual post (wad)

Comment: @O.Don when you type `rails routes` under the `prefix` column you should find the name of the route that you should use, usually to send the id you just send it the object which holds the id you want to get. if you will add the route list to the question, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: If you access the object, you have the idea, what about being more explicit? `wads_path(id: music_wad.id)`

Comment: @SebastianPalma @O.Don i think i know what the problem is. you should use a singular name in the path and not plural when trying to link to a show page (or any other singular path like edit / delete etc) so: `<%= link_to wad_path(music_wad) do %>` should work properly. (use `wad` and not `wads`)

Comment: Thank you both so much! You were right @ZivGalili. I followed your recommendation and it worked - thanks also for explaining why the issue occurred. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: @O.Don i've added an answer explaining it, so others with same problem will have a solution! ^^ Have fun writing RoR code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resources :wads` will create some routes that you can use.

Running `rails routes` (on rails 5) or `rake routes` (on rails 4 and lower) in the console will give you the list of your routes.

Under the `prefix` column you could find the correct route name you should use and under the `URI Pattern` you could see the actual address it links to.

You asked for `wads/:id` so the link should be `<%= link_to wad_path(wad_music) do %>` (the prefix is `wad_path` and you need to give it the object which holds the `id` - or an id...)

Since you want to link to a singular action - meaning that the action will get and id of an object - and get it (gets a single object!) the link prefix will be in singular form as well: `wad_path` and not `wads_path`

(`wads_path` will link to the `index` action in the controller and doesn't need to get any object or id)